# How to include html file on click link

Tags: javascript, html

Hi i want to include a  file on link click here  following code  i did but it is not working in my html page

here is my code given below

```
    $("#reset").click(function() {
          $(function() {
              $("#RightPaneContainerDiv").html('<iframe src="open.php"></iframe>');
          });
    });
     <a href="#" id="reset"></a>
```

where i am wrong in following code

How can i achieve my output

Answer (score 1):

You are binding the JavaScript handler to the link before you are including the link in your HTML.

After the click event fires, you are delaying the reaction until the DOM is ready — it is highly unlikely that the DOM will not be ready by the time the link is clicked.

Swap your two event handlers.

Wait for the DOM to be ready. Then bind the event handler.

```
$(function() {
    $("#reset").click(function() {
        $("#RightPaneContainerDiv").html('<iframe src="open.php"></iframe>');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I'm seeing is

> $(function() {

when you do a .click function, do not invoke ready function so your code should be like this:

```
     $("#reset").click(function() {

              $("#RightPaneContainerDiv").html('<iframe src="open.php"></iframe>');

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function resetclick() {
    $("#yourDiv").html('<iframe src="open.php"></iframe>');
  }
</script>
 <a href="#" onclick="resetclick()" id="reset">fafa</a>
<div id="yourDiv">

</div>
```

This should work fine. In your code you have:

```
function() {
          $(function() {
```

Don't really know what you are trying to do with it. Remove one function() or use my code.

Comment: when i am trying  this code  its showing message Access Forbidden

Comment: here is my  phpfile  <?php

echo "shakti";
?>

Comment: I can't see a reason why it shouldn't work. Have you used my code?

Comment: yes i used  your code here when i include html file in place oh php it works

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Don't forget to use `preventDefault()` when the target is an `<a>`.

```
 $("#reset").click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $("#RightPaneContainerDiv").html('<iframe src="open.php"></iframe>');
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function loadjscssfile(filename, filetype){
  var fileref=document.createElement('script')
  fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")
  fileref.setAttribute("src", filename)
 }
 if (typeof fileref!="undefined")
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
}


loadjscssfile("file.html", "html") //dynamically load "file.html" as a JavaScript file
```